# How to force add-in to refresh from server, not cache?

Tags: office-js

There have been considerable issues in the past with clients being left running outdated add-in code. We've tried reinstalling the add-in, right-click > "Refresh" in the task pane, and a reboot of the system, none of which have worked. The only way we have been able to do it is to get clients to clear their Office cache, which is clearly unacceptable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache

With a major release of our product around the corner, we need to be able to ensure that all clients are running the latest version of our add-in from the server, not the cached version from their system.

Is there any way to disable caching for the Office add-in runtime?

Can provide server response headers if necessary. We are hosting the add-in with Azure Premium CDN.

Comment: What are your cache-control settings on the server where you host the files? Setting max-age to something really short seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to force update add-in is to update version number in Manifest file and resubmit offer for publishing. This will force all exiting user to update offer at their end. It will result iin getting latest manifest file from server rathen than picking from cache.

Comment: This is not an option for us. We cannot afford to wait for Microsoft to accept our submission, which often takes upwards of 1 week incl. debugging. Is there no other option here?